# Ubuntu 19.10 dual boot, can't find computer's harddrive for installation

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gpt

I tried to install Ubuntu 19.10 in the usual dual boot configuration on my new Dell Latitude 5500. It came with BitLocker encryption on its 512GB drive. I shrank the volume to about 200GB for Ubuntu, disabled the encryption and waited for Windows to decrypt the drive. I also switched off Windows fast boot. So far so good. The laptop's drive has a GPT table, so I used Rufus to make a bootable Ubuntu USB with GPT as well.

But when I boot into the USB via UEFI from the Dell BIOS and try to do the Ubuntu installation, the installer tells me that I don't have enough space, and that my laptop only has 7.8GB of space. The USB I'm using is 8GB, so most likely the installer is seeing that, and can't find the 512GB drive in the laptop at all. I've done a few dozen dual boot installations ever since becoming a Linux user, and I've never encountered this problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Would you please also run `sudo parted -l` from the LiveUSB in a terminal window, then copy the results, click [edit], and paste them into your question? Please don't use Add Comment as it loses the formatting.

Comment: See also: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2436198

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check in the bios whether the sata configuration is in RAID mode or AHCI mode.
If it is in RAID mode(!Important: Don't change the setting directly), restart windows in safe mode and change the option to AHCI and then check if the drive is recognised.